# iOS animate button while scrolling list

Tags: ios, animation, uiscrollview

I have view with UITableView. Above this list I have UIButton. I need to implement an animation what will move button vertically according to scrolling on list and return to base location when scrolling is finished. I show scrolling down in pictures bellow:

1. This is not scrolled list:

[image]

2. This is list scrolled to half:

[image]

3. This is list fully scrolled:

[image]

For now I detect start and stop scrolling list events and do animation like that:

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;

    CGRect newFrame = button.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y = screenHeight - (newFrame.size.height/2.0);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2
                     animations:^{
                         button.frame = newFrame;
                     }];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGRect newFrame = storedButtonFrame;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2
                     animations:^{
                         button.frame = newFrame;
                     }];
}
```

I have few issues with this First is that when I scrolling down my animation is animating to then end and I want to animate based on scrolled list eg. when I scroll down list for 10px I would like to move button only for 10px not to the end of list. Second is that I get stop scroll event when begin scroll animation is still running the start animation is blink to the end and the end animation is start animating what is definitly what I dont want. I dont have to much experiance in iOS and I really dont have any ide how can I do this. Have any idea how can I do something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` you could use `scrollViewDidScroll:` like so:

```
/// Animate the button position as the scroll view scrolls
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat percentage = scrollView.contentOffset.y / scrollView.contentSize.height;

    CGRect frame = _button.frame;
    frame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y + percentage * self.tableView.frame.size.height;
    _button.frame = frame;
}

/// Animate the button back to the top-right corner
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGRect frame = _button.frame;
    frame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f
                     animations:^{
                         _button.frame = frame;
                     }];
}
```

This makes the button follow the scroll indicator as you scroll the list. `scrollViewDidScroll:` fires very often so the movement is smooth.

When the list stops, it goes back to its default position at the top-right, which you get from `contentOffset.y`.

Comment: Awesome! If you could mark the answer as solved I'd appreciate it :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about it :)